# How to find parts of text that answer a "why"

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-classification

Given some text that describes something,
how to tag / identify parts of the text
that explain specific aspects - what, who, why?

For example, given the following input text...

```
Evaporation is an essential part of the water cycle.
The sun (solar energy) drives evaporation of water 
from oceans, lakes, moisture in the soil, and other
sources of water.

In hydrology, evaporation and transpiration
(which involves evaporation within plant stomata)
are collectively termed evapotranspiration.

Evaporation of water occurs when the surface of 
the liquid is exposed, allowing molecules to escape
and form water vapor; this vapor can then rise up
and form clouds. With sufficient energy,
the liquid will turn into vapor.
```

How would one go about obtaining output like this:

```
What = "Evaporation", "Hydrology", "Evapotranspiration", "Vapor"  
 Who = ""  
 Why = "surface of the liquid is exposed, allowing molecules to escape", "With sufficient energy"
```

Could a [parts-of-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) tagging framework help here?
Which **parts-of-speech** should be mapped as answering a **why**.

*<sub>PS: Is there a term for this already? PoS-Tagging and Sentiment-Analysis are close but not quite what this is, right?</sub>*